# Table sort icons are not changing correctly in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

table header sort icon is not changing correctly, if I click on ID it is sorting the icon but
if I click on ID and again click on firstName the ID sort icon is changing not the firstName sort icon (icons are not updating uniquely) please help

```
  function changeSort(key: SortKeys) {
    setSortOrder(sortOrder === "ascn" ? "desc" : "ascn");

    setSortKey(key);
  }
```

here is the code [code-sandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-bartik-0dsvvn?file=/src/components/SortableTable.tsx)

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

```
function changeSort(key: SortKeys) {
    setSortOrder(sortOrder === "ascn" ? "desc" : "ascn");

    setSortKey(key);
}
```

to

```
function changeSort(key: SortKeys) {
    setSortOrder(sortOrder === "ascn" || sortKey !== key ? "desc" : "ascn");

    setSortKey(key);
}
```

sortKey !== key
you need to check because the sortOrder state i can be desc so clicking on another one is ascn again which makes it look like nothing happened.

Comment: it is working fine emir, _thanks for your time_